# How to emit namespaced tags and attributes with data.xml 0.2.0-alpha6 for Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

My aim is to emit a xml element with namespaced tags and attributes.

I've tried to build some dummy namespaces for that problem. Like xmlns.foo. But that didn't work out. The following simple example shows a test case.

```
(ns app.main
  (:require [clojure.data.xml :as xml]))

(xml/emit-str
 (xml/element
  :foo:bar
  {:foo:name "foo" :foo:type "foo-type"}
  "baz"))
```

It should be

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<foo:bar foo:name=\"foo\" foo:type=\"foo-type\">baz</foo:bar>"
```

Sadly the actual output is 
NamespaceError: An attempt was made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces dom.cljs:32:63

````
    cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$3 dom.cljs:32
    clojure$data$xml$js$dom$element_node dom.cljs:105
    cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$variadic xml.cljs:45
    clojure$data$xml$emit_str xml.cljs:40
    <anonymous> main.cljs:7 ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Look here:  https://github.com/clojure/data.xml#namespace-support

---

Just tried it with plain xml.  Config in `deps.edn`:

```
       org.clojure/data.xml   {:mvn/version "0.2.0-alpha6"}
```

Plain XML works.  Declare the namespace:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:require
    [clojure.data.xml :as xml] ...))

(let [tags (xml/element :foo {:foo-attr "foo value"}
             (xml/element :bar {:bar-attr "bar value"}
               (xml/element :baz {} "The baz value")))]
  (t/spyx (xml/emit-str tags)) )
```

with result:

```
(xml/emit-str tags) => 
"<foo foo-attr=\"foo value\">
  <bar bar-attr=\"bar value\">
    <baz>The baz value</baz></bar></foo>"
```

Namespaces seem to be still a work in progress for ClojureScript. This method fails:

```
   (xml/alias-uri 'xh "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
   (xml/emit-str {:tag     ::xh/html
                  :content [{:tag ::xh/head}
                            {:tag ::xh/body :content ["DOCUMENT"]}]}))
```

but this method works:

```
   (xml/emit-str {:tag   "{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}html"   ; `::xh/html` fails
                  :content [{:tag "{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}head" }
                            {:tag "{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}body" :content ["DOCUMENT"]}]}))
```

with result:

```
 "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
    <head></head>
    <body>DOCUMENT</body></html>"
```

So it does not declare an alias like `a` and prefix each tag like 
`a:head`.

Perhaps you should file an issue on the project:  https://github.com/clojure/data.xml